# Python 3x, syntaxError: can't assign to literal

Tags: python

I'm new to programing and I was playing with python what I've so far learnt form the tutorial that was where I encounter with an Error. I'd like to know what it means by the **syntax Error:  can't assign to literal** and how to understand/ read the message so that the next time I can solve it myself. It's not that I don't like asking questions but a question this simple I expect myself to be able to answer it or at least know how to find an answer for it. Thanks in advance! :) 
here is what I did

```
>>> 1 = 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal (<pyshell#0>, line 1)
>>> 1 = 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal (<pyshell#1>, line 1)
>>> 1 != 1
False
>>>
```

as you can see python gave me answer for the last question which is 1 != 1.

Comment: Please post your code too...

Comment: You copied only the last part of the message. Please show the *full* traceback(the whole output, starting with `Traceback ...`). From what you wrote is clear that you tried to do something like `"something" = value`, when it should have been `something = value`(note the missing quotes `"`).

Comment: As iCodez points out, you can't assign a value to a literal, which is what int values are.  The '=' sign assigns a value to a reference, it's not a boolean operator for equality.  Try this instead: 1 == 1.

Answer (score 5):

You probably meant "==", which compares for equality.

```
>>> 1==1
True
```

A single equal sign means assignment, which roughly means to *change* what's to the left of the sign to match what's to the right. Trying to change a constant returns an error.

Comment: I think all the other answers missed the point... the OP clearly confused `=` with `==`.

Answer (score 2):

That error is generated when you try to make a variable out of a literal.  See examples below:

```
>>> 1 = 'a'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
>>> 'a' = 'a'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
>>> 1.0 = 'a'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
>>>
```

In Python, you can't make variables out of numbers, strings, etc.  Only text (that isn't a reserved word) that starts with either a letter or an underscore can be made a variable:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
>>> _a = 1
>>> _a
1
>>>
```

Comment: You can `True = SomeRandomVariable (ex '1')` in Python2

Comment: @Vik2015 - Right.  I'm used to Python 3.x. :)

Comment: @Vik2015: `True` isn't a literal. It's a keyword. (You get a `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword` if you try to do `True = False` in Python 3)

Answer (score 1):

This means that you're trying to assign a value to a literal (colloquially, something other than a variable). For example:

```
x = 1 # This is fine, x is a variable
1 = 1 # This fails, as 1 is a value, not a variable
"abcd" = 1 # This also fails, as "abcd" is a string literal
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is a literal; so are numbers. You can assign values to a variable (give them a name), but you can't change the value of a string, e. g.:

```
>>> a = "Hello"   # OK
>>> "Hello" = a   # Not OK
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
>>> 1 = 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: I wasn't assigning them. I just found what I did wrong. I was comparing them but I forgot I should have used to == signs instead of one. thanks for all the answers. :) it was just a small confusion!

Comment: @user2856873: Well, if you used one `=` then you *were*  assigning them.